# When using Promise.All for multiple ajax requests, how do I assign that data to a local variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to use Promise.All() three times. Each one for a specific array of ajax requests that call a function in my code-behind that returns a jsonresult. Is there a way I can get the array return from promise.all and assign it to local array. I originally tried using async:false on ajax but it is incredibly slow. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by local variable do you mean `let values = Promise.all([...])`? Promise.all returns a new promise that will resolve/throw when all promises are resolved. Any usage of the variable will have to be done through promises or other callbacks. e.i. `Promise.all([...]).then((values) => {...})`. Alternatively if you are able to use async/await you can `var values = await Promise.all([....])`

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! `Promise.all` returns an array, with each element in the output corresponding to the elements of the input.

```js
let asyncResults = await Promise.all([
    asyncOp0(),
    asyncOp1(),
    asyncOp2()
])
```

At this point, `asyncResults` is a local array.

`asyncResults[0]` will be the return of asyncOp0

`asyncResults[1]` will be the return of asyncOp1

`asyncResults[2]` will be the return of asyncOp2

It sounds like that's exactly what you want.

If it's not returning fast enough for you, the likely culprit is the HTTP endpoint you're hitting. You should study the performance of that endpoint. Alternatively, if the HTTP response is very large, bad performance is just a consequence of that. The remedy might require you to redesign the server API to return a smaller representation of the data you care about.